# How to fix this - The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher

Tags: android, flutter, dart

`When I try to run flutter build apk

The plugins `geocoder, google_map_location_picker` use a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures or future build failures, try to see if these plugins support the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing them since a
future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.3.40 and higher.
  The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
  project ':google_map_location_picker' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           11.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1.`

Comment: I have tried updating to the latest In project-level build.Gradle, ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' 
and also Then in app level build.gradle, I updated my dependencies to have this: implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"

Comment: Hi @Yasar Hasan Bin Gursain did you manage to find a solution to this??? I am having the exact same problem